# Python script to remove erroneous characters from a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, parsing, python-2.x

I have an automatically generated CSV file which provides the data I need, but some individual cells have extra characters in the cell.

```
COLUMN1           COLUMN2          COLUMN3
'Foo325GoodData'  Bar:388GoodData  383GoodData
'Foo123GoodData'  Bar:998GoodData  293GoodData
```

I need to remove the foo, the bar, the quotes and the colon without altering the 3 digit data.

Here's the code I tried, but it just deletes all of my data:

```
 import csv
 import string

 input_file = open('data.csv', 'r')
 output_file = open('data_cleaned.csv', 'w')
 data = csv.reader(input_file)
 writer = csv.writer(output_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
 foo = 'foo'
 bar = '"bar:u'

 for line in data:
     line = str(line)
     new_line = str.replace(line,foo,'')
     new_line2 = str.replace(line,bar,'')
     writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))
     writer.writerow(new_line2.split(','))
```

Per gboffi's instructions below, I tried the following:

> cleaner.py < bad.csv > good.csv

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 from sys import stdin


 q = '"' + "'"
 number = 'foo:'

 print(next(stdin) , end='')

 for line in stdin:

     toks = [tok.strip(q).lstrip(number) for tok in line.split()]

     print(' '.join(toks))
```

This generates a new CSV, but none of the bad data seems to be getting removed.

Comment: Why would you write Python to do that? Why not `sed`?

Comment: You can import re: and use `new_line = re.sub('[^0-9 ]+','',str(line))`

Comment: `perl` or `sed` will definitely solve your problem much quicker

Comment: since you have no spaces, you can rather use `new_line = re.sub('\\D+','',str(line))`

Comment: I suggest you apply some basic debugging skills -- you'll see the problem soon enough.  When you make a new value, print out the resulting variable right away: `line`, `new_line`, and `new_line2`.

Comment: If you want to remove the string `Bar:`, why are you calling `replace` with the completely different string `"bar:u`? Even without any other errors, that’s pretty obviously not going to work.

Comment: This snippet removed all of the symbols other than numerals, then pushed all of the numerals into column 1 squished together: 

     new_line = re.sub('\\D+','',str(line))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove everything that is not a digit or a space, why don't you use a variation on this idea

```
for line in data:
    print(''.join(c for c in line if c in '0123456789 '))
```

where we stick together (`''.join(...)`) only the wanted characters in each of the  input line?

---

***Update***

The previous answer remains because it's perfect for the requirements the OP originally expressed (see the edit history of the question).

However, given the *new* requirements the OP has given, they could try to use the following code

```
$ cat nofubar.py 
from sys import stdin

q = '"' + "'"             # we want to remove the 'q'outes
foobar = 'FooBar:'        # and also Foo, Bar and ':' too...

print(next(stdin), end='') # print the header line to stdout, note end=''

for line in stdin:

    # strip quotes on both sides,
    # strip (all) the characters in foobar * only on the left *
    toks = [tok.strip(q).lstrip(foobar) for tok in line.split()]

    print(' '.join(toks))
$
```

Let's put this new code to test

```
$ python nofubar.py << END > good.csv
COLUMN1           COLUMN2          COLUMN3
'Foo325GoodData'  Bar:388GoodData  383GoodData
'Foo123GoodData'  Bar:998GoodData  293GoodData
END
$ cat good.csv 
COLUMN1           COLUMN2          COLUMN3
325GoodData 388GoodData 383GoodData
123GoodData 998GoodData 293GoodData
$
```

---

Assuming that the file with extraneous characters is named `bad.csv` you can connect it to `stdin` using the [input redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial#input_redirection_n_file) symbol `<` on the shell command line

```
$ python nofubar.py < bad.csv > good.csv
$
```

Comment: My fault, the data isn't all digits. There are both digits and text.

Comment: Starting from the line `'Foo325GoodData'  Bar:388GoodData  383GoodData`, is it`325GoodData 388GoodData 383GoodData` what you want?  At any rate, could you please [edit] your question and _show exactly the result that you expect_ given the sample data that you have shown?

Comment: That's certainly the output I'm looking for. Where do I open up the source .csv file?

Comment: I have edited my answer to account for your last comment.

Comment: Really appreciate the update. I understand what you're doing here. Not sure why but when I run it my console just kicks me to a > prompt. 

I did have to import __future__ because I'm on 2.7...

Comment: `'>'` is probably [a secondary prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323578/164535) and it is shown from the shell when the shell thinks the previous command was not properly completed.  The most probable explanation is that you introduced a spurious quotation mark in your command line, but this is just a guess... What you have to write in the command line is (possibly with different filenames) `python < bad > good` — re Python 2 vs 3, the only thing that you may want to add is `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: ^ Got the script to run. It is writing data to the good.csv... The only problem is that it's not actually removing any of the extra characters. :D

Comment: My answer is perfectly OK as long as the matter is to  take the data _as you have shown it_ and print the data _modified as you have shown it_. ፨ My guess  is that your real requirements are rather different from what you showed in the different edits of your question and, seemingly, you are unable to adapt my answer to your real problem.  I'm not interested on keeping this converstion alive any more. My best regards.

Comment: gboffi, I have no doubt that it is my mistake and I'm messing something up. I run this command from the console: python cleaner.py < ciscsc61.csv > good.csv. I use the exact code you posted. My output file is created, but the data in it is exactly the same as the data in the source file. 

Here is my code: 

from __future__ import print_function
from sys import stdin

 
q = '"' + "'"
number = 'text:'

print(next(stdin) , end='')

for line in stdin:

    toks = [tok.strip(q).lstrip(number) for tok in line.split()]

    print(' '.join(toks))

Comment: If I play with it a little bit, I can get it to remove the 'bar:' portion of the bad data, but I have no idea why it will only do that part.

Comment: I figured it out. Your method worked, but I needed to use toks.replace instead of strip and lstrip. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the arguments, that must be passing to replace() method: first arg. is what to replace, and second arg. is with what to replace. Just remove line from str.replace(line,bar,''). replace is a method and first "hidden" argument is *self*, that means to use the metod on the object which invoke this method i.e. on `str` var in your case

Comment: Your hint helped, I can get it to remove one of the sets of characters from one column... But it won't do different text on two columns and it adds brackets at the beginning and end of each row.

Comment: About quots: try to use in csv.writer  csv.QUOTE_NONE for quoting parameter. For split() method use  whitespace as parameter:
split(' ')

Comment: Why do you suppose it wouldn't let me change two cells in the same script?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = 'foo"12jko'
bar = '"bar:u2345'

foo = "".join([i for i in list(foo) if i.isdigit()])
bar = "".join([i for i in list(bar) if i.isdigit()])

print(foo, bar)
```

Result,

```
12 2345
```

Debug your code per your requirements. 
Using regular expressions is the best option.